# Form Validation in Play framework

Tags: java, json, validation, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am creating a Play application with Play 2.3 in Java.

I'm trying to use Form for handling POST request with JSON body.

My problem is that if my JSON is a simple object with only Strings or Floats attribute, it works well. But if I put some of Object imbrication, it continue to bind the request corectly but don't do the Constraints validation in nested objects.

Here an exemple of what I'm trying to do :

```
public class PairRequest
{
    @Required
    public String epc;

    @Required
    public RequestProduct product;
}

public class RequestProduct
{
    //Product data
    @Constraints.Required
    private String productCode;

    @Constraints.Required
    public Brand brand;

    @Constraints.Required
    private String furniture;
}

@Entity
public class Brand extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @Column(length = 250)
    @Constraints.Required
    public String name;

    @Column(nullable = true, length = 512)
    public String regex;
}
```

Have I missed something ? It's weird because I think it was working during first times... But I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only the annotation `@Required` is needed but also the `@Valid` for complex objects, as pointed out here: [Bind complex (JSON) form data automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456040/bind-complex-json-form-data-automatically/20620619#comment-50344735)